# Changing The Font Of A DataGrid Cell?

Tags: c#, gridview, fonts

My simple goal is to make the font inside of a particular cell bold.  I can't set the Style.Font.Bold property because it is read only, but I can set Style.Font to a new Font object.  How do I create a Font object to make it possible to bold the text inside of a particular cell?

```
grid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.Font = new Font(???);
```

Thanks Stack-O!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we're talking about WinForms, you can do it like this...

```
var cell = grid.Rows[0].Cells[0];
cell.Style.Font = new Font(cell.Style.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

If we're talking about a web application, you can do it like this...

```
grid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style("font-weight", "bold");
```

But ideally in a web app this would be handled via CSS with a specific selector...

```
#GridView1 > tr:first-child > td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Of course, if it's not a web-app but a WinForm app, then the CSS comment would not apply... :)

Comment: cell.Style.Font: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (it's null)

Comment: @Soo Then you must be applying this code at a time when the cell does not exist.

Comment: @sooprise: I've seen that too, and the cell most certainly did exist.  My workaround was use the `DataGridView`'s `Font` property instead, but that only works if your cell uses the same font.